# Из консоли без кавычек

Tags: javascript, консоль

Все доброго дня.

Подскажите, как вывести данные из консоли без кавычек?

Полный код почему-то не отправился, укажу вывод :

```
 console.log(makex() ,  makeSim(), makex(), '=');
```

Соответственно результат в консоли :
5 "+" 7 "="

Вопрос в следующем, как сделать вывод в сам файл в формате - 1+2= ?
То есть, пытаюсь сделать просто генератор примеров (еще бы прикрутить проверку, чтобы ответ не был отрицательным)
Спасибо.

Comment: консоль выводит то что вы передаете, отформатируйте рзультат выполнения своих функций и консоль выведет что нужно

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(makex() + makeSim() + makex() + '=');
```